# Create Subarray from Associative Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, associative-array

Within my node.js app I have managed to retrieve userinput and proceed to scrape a unique table for each user to recieve the following associative array, called **self.items**

When I call the following:

```
console.log(self.items)
```

I recieve the following output for a specific user.

```
[ { Wins: 5,
    Losses: 1,
    Points: 33 },
  { Wins: 3,
    Losses: 1,
    Points: 21 },
  { Wins: 3,
    Losses: 0,
    Points: 18 } ]
```

Because I intend to visualize the data with d3.js I would like to simplify the associative array into 3 managable simple arrays, such that for each key there would be a simple array created with all of the corresponding values. The following output is what I am seeking:

```
console.log(wins) => [5,3,3]

console.log(losses) => [1,1,0]

console.log(points) => [33,21,18]
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Create 3 arrays. Loop the returned array and assign them appropriately? A google search would have helped you here

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Would you mind elaborating on how to perform the forementioned loop? I have attempted searching, but was unable to find anything straightforward.

Comment: What did you attempt to search

Comment: http://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/01/associative-arrays-in-javascript/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: That doesn't mention looping the array at all. Come on, google is powerful you can do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 3 empty arrays (wins, losses, points). Simply loop through your array using a [for...loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) which using the [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) to determine how many elements there are.

Use [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add the individual parts to their respective arrays.

```
var data = [ 
{ 
    Wins: 5,
    Losses: 1,
    Points: 33 
},
{ 
    Wins: 3,
    Losses: 1,
    Points: 21 
},
{ 
    Wins: 3,
    Losses: 0,
    Points: 18 
}];

var wins = [], losses = [], points = [];
for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++)
{
    wins.push(data[i].Wins);
    losses.push(data[i].Losses);    
    points.push(data[i].Points);    
}

console.log(wins);
console.log(losses);
console.log(points);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leetaylor/7Rp6a/)

Comment: @RUJordan Point taken. Better?

Comment: Yes. That's all I ever wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Because you know the structure, you can simply do it.

```
var wins = [], losses = [], points = [], item;
for (var i=0; i < self.items.length; i++) {
    item = self.items[i];
    wins.push(item.Wins);
    losses.push(item.Losses);
    points.push(item.Points);
}
```

Comment: Using a `for .. in` loop is not recommended for indexed arrays iirc

Comment: Now try explaining your answer, because if the OP knew what loops were he wouldn't have asked.

Comment: Checking Comprehension: So this would loop through the initial associative array, starting with the first array iterating through the last, and for each key in each array pushes the value into a new array of that specific key?

Comment: Now it pushes it to a new index, ie 0,1,2,3,4, you can edit the code to push it to a specific key.